# Self-hosted LAN over Internet solution like Hamachi

Tags: vpn, lan, tunnel, hamachi

I'd like to setup VPN that offers LAN over Internet in much the same way a Hamachi mesh style server allows peers on the network to directly talk using IPs on the interface while directing regular traffic to the main network adapter (eth0 or wlan0 for example).

I have a great amount of resources, but I can't seem to find a setup that fits. I have looked into SoftEther but it seems like it is just out of my needs.

My need is to create a Mesh VPN server on my home server (which has a public IP) and manually connect to it (in much the same way as Hamachi) so that my peers can interact with my home computer as a central server. I need this to connect to some of my work computers while I am out of state. My main concern is tunneling UDP traffic.

Is there any self-hosted Hamachi-like solution that does not act as a gateway but as a LAN over Internet?

Answer (score 4):

> that does not act as a gateway but as a LAN over Internet?

Nearly *all* VPN software can act like that. In fact, that's usually the default. Just don't configure the server to provide a default route in the first place, and that's it – you get a VPN that works only for its specific subnet.

That said, if you want a mesh:

The usual recommendation is **[Tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/)** (possibly even the 1.1 branch). It seems to be capable of setting up arbitrary mesh topologies with relaying, at either IP layer or Ethernet layer (switch mode). Broadcast is supported (multicast packets are handled as broadcast).

**[ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/)** is somewhere in the middle: it tries to use direct connections whenever possible (even punching through NATs), but falls back to relaying via supernodes otherwise. It's possible to host your own controller and supernode, though rarely necessary. Multicast and broadcast is supported (with limits).

Then there is **[OpenVPN](https://github.com/openvpn/openvpn)**, which is rather strictly client-server-based. (It has a client-to-client flag, but doesn't have NAT holepunching capabilities.) A regular OpenVPN server sounds like it'd work fine for you, but if you set it up in *tap* mode (as opposed to the default *tun*), then it'll relay arbitrary Ethernet traffic instead of being limited to IP.

*(All of the above work on Linux, FreeBSD, and Windows.)*

Finally, depending on the OS, there are plenty of lightweight, *manually* configured tunnel types – such as GRE or L2TP. They get somewhat unwieldy once the network grows, since you have to set up every point-to-point link by hand (no hole punching; no encryption unless you add IPsec), but ... they're basically the duct tape of networking.

---

Note that there probably isn't any software that supports *all* platforms out there, so in some cases you'll just need to route packets between 2 or 3 networks. For example, you might want to run Tinc on PCs but connect via OpenVPN from an iPhone. That's fine, as long as the OpenVPN server has a route for the Tinc subnet, and vice versa. (The same goes for routing between the "LAN over Internet" and your *regular* LAN.)

Comment: So ZeroTier tries to do persistant NAT hole-punching with the server as a broker, but has a VPN style fallback?

Comment: @TrevorRudolph: Yes – and it's still a VPN either way. "VPN" doesn't imply central relaying of any sort.

Comment: Yes understood. I have to do some research on the different network Layers (2 vs 3)

Comment: In short: you need a L2 VPN for protocols which do not run over IP. (For example, MPLS; IPX or AppleTalk (for old games); IS-IS; ...) Pure IP-based communications work with both kinds, although L3 has slightly less overhead (no Ethernet header inside the tunnel).

Comment: Yes I'd rather reduce overhead. I'll shoot for L3. I can probably set up OpenVPN in TUN mode as my communications routes are <100mbps, I doubt I need a mesh network if my data flow looks like Travel Location -> Server -> Work Devices behind Office NAT. I'd usually use an ssh tunnel but the program I am working on does it's own port selection.

Comment: You don't need a mesh, but it can certainly reduce _latency_ if the software manages to establish a direct connection. Unless your VPN server is also hosted at work, that is. Still, OpenVPN in "topology subnet; tls-server" mode is a good start.